# How can I keep my context menu from spilling onto another monitor in C#?

Tags: c#, contextmenu

I've been learning C# lately, and I'm working on a context menu for a notifyicon. The context menu comes up just fine, but if the menu is too large to fit, it'll spill over onto my monitor to the right.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @LarsTech: Presumably the right-click to open the menu occurs somewhere near the right edge of the first monitor.  Since there are two monitors, the menu spills over onto the right monitor instead of sliding to the left like it normally would with a single monitor.

Comment: @Rob Do you have any multi-monitor based addons installed onto your own PC (such as Display Fusion Pro)?

Comment: Indeed I do, @JMK. Display Fusion Pro.

Comment: Maybe try disabling that add-on and see if you still experience your issue, or if you have access to another multi-monitor PC without Display fusion pro try your application on that?

Comment: Still does, but only with long menus, it seems. Other (more professionally made) programs aren't seeming to be affected by it, though. They work as expected with or without displayfusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that I can re-create this problem as shown below:

[image: Problem]

The solution seems to be to change the **RightToLeft** property of the context menu to **Yes** (right click on the menu, click properties and then select **RightToLeft** from the properties pane), so my context menu now looks like so:

[image: Solution]

Hope this helps!